# How to enable spark-history server for standalone cluster non hdfs mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have setup Spark2.1.1 cluster (1 master 2 slaves) following http://paxcel.net/blog/how-to-setup-apache-spark-standalone-cluster-on-multiple-machine/ in standalone mode.
I do not have a pre-Hadoop setup on of the machine. I wanted to start spark-history server.
I run it as follows:

```
roshan@bolt:~/spark/spark_home/sbin$ ./start-history-server.sh
```

and in the spark-defaults.conf I set this:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
```

But it fails with the error:

```
7/06/29 22:59:03 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(roshan); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(roshan); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/06/29 22:59:03 INFO FsHistoryProvider: History server ui acls disabled; users with admin permissions: ; groups with admin permissions
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer$.main(HistoryServer.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer.main(HistoryServer.scala)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Log directory specified does not exist: file:/tmp/spark-events Did you configure the correct one through spark.history.fs.logDirectory?
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.org$apache$spark$deploy$history$FsHistoryProvider$$startPolling(FsHistoryProvider.scala:214)
```

What I should set to `spark.history.fs.logDirectory` and `spark.eventLog.dir`

**Update 1:**

```
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.history.fs.logDirectory   file:////home/roshan/spark/spark_home/logs
spark.eventLog.dir               file:////home/roshan/spark/spark_home/logs
```

but I am always getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Codec [1] is not available. Consider setting spark.io.compression.codec=snappy at org.apache.spark.io.Co
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default spark defines `file:/tmp/spark-events` as the log directory for history server and your log clearly says *spark.history.fs.logDirectory* is not configured

first of all you need to create *spark-events* folder in */tmp* (which is not a good idea as */tmp* is refreshed everytime a machine is rebooted) and then add *spark.history.fs.logDirectory* in *spark-defaults.conf* to point to that directory. But I suggest you create another folder which spark user has access to and update *spark-defaults.conf* file.

You need to define two more variables in **spark-defaults.conf** file

```
spark.eventLog.dir              file:path to where you want to store your logs
spark.history.fs.logDirectory   file:same path as above
```

Suppose you want to store in */opt/spark-events* where *spark user* has access to then above parameters in *spark-defaults.conf* would be

```
spark.eventLog.enabled          true
spark.eventLog.dir              file:/opt/spark-events
spark.history.fs.logDirectory   file:/opt/spark-events
```

You can find more information in [Monitoring and Instrumentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)

Comment: Thanks I set it SPARK_HOME/log directory but I am continuously getting the error: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Codec [1] is not available. Consider setting spark.io.compression.codec=snappy
 at org.apache.spark.io.Co
I tried setting this in spark-defaults.conf but still getting the error.

Comment: can I see what did you set? You can update your question saying you updated as I said.

Comment: Updated, please see.

Comment: why did you put four back-slashes? either three or one will only work.

Comment: try restarting your computer, did you?

Comment: didn't this answer helped you @RoshanMehta?

Answer (score -5):

Try setting

```
spark.io.compression.codec=org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec
```

in **spark-defaults.conf**

Comment: how is that related?

Comment: This doesn't help the issue at hand and is completely unrelated.