# Spark Submit error when running a JAR from Azure Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks

I'm trying to issue spark submit from Azure Databricks jobs scheduler, currently stuck with the below error. Error says: File file:/tmp/spark-events does not exist. I need some pointers to understand do we need to create this directory in Azure blob location(which is my storage Layer) or in Azure DBFS location.

As per the below link, not so clear where to create the directory when running the spark-submit from Azure Databricks jobs scheduler.

[SparkContext Error - File not found /tmp/spark-events does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38350249/sparkcontext-error-file-not-found-tmp-spark-events-does-not-exist)

Error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Warning: Ignoring non-Spark config property: eventLog.rolloverIntervalSeconds
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.dta.dl.ct.qm.hbase.reverse.pipeline.HBaseVehicleMasterLoad.main(HBaseVehicleMasterLoad.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/spark-events does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.start(EventLoggingListener.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:580)
    at com.dta.dl.ct.qm.hbase.reverse.pipeline.HBaseVehicleMasterLoad$.<init>(HBaseVehicleMasterLoad.scala:32)
    at com.dta.dl.ct.qm.hbase.reverse.pipeline.HBaseVehicleMasterLoad$.<clinit>(HBaseVehicleMasterLoad.scala)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create this folder on the driver node before collecting event logs (that's by design).

To do so, one way could be adding the property `spark.history.fs.logDirectory` (present at the spark-defaults.conf file) on a global init script as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure#--spark-configuration).

Please make sure that the folder defined on that property exist and can be accessed from the driver node